# Error while running tomcat : Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, maven-2, tomcat7

I am getting following exception while running tomcat from cygwin. could someone please help to solve this problem.

> **with Command:** sh catalina.sh run -config conf/mySchema.xml
>   **Project type:** maven
>   **System RAM:** 8gb

my setenv.bat having following cofiguratation

> JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=31"

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
'nrecognized VM option 'MaxTenuringThreshold=31